# Do I need to make 2 different applications for using GCM in android?

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I tried searching these issues. Some sites say I need to do some stuff with php in order to make 3rd party server while  others don't mention anything. some says it need JSON. Guide me please. PS I am a beginner and know java, XML,SQL only.

Comment: Use comments to reply to other users or notify them of changes. If you are adding new information, edit your post instead of commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need one server.  The second server you are reading about may be the Google GCM cloud server?  When I did a GCM project a few years ago, I had one server, it happened to be a App Engine instance.  It generated events and sent them to Google via the GCM api and then onto onto the device.  I don't remember it being that difficult.

I did have more than one server in the mix though, there were others that sent messages to the AppEngine server, but it was not required to send a GCM message.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)** is a service that enables developers to send data from servers to both Android applications or Chrome apps and extensions.

So if you want to send data to the users of your App then you must have an interface or dashboard from where you can send some data (typically push notification) to the users of your app.

This dashboard (server from which you can send data) can be developed by using PHP or any script languages.

Now a though can come up in your mind:

> "I am suppose to develop both the mobile app and the server then what
>   role does GCM play?"

Yes, GCM is playing a vital role indeed. The server we have to develop is just to design an interface so that you can type your message/notification and select the recipients. Rest of the part of (managing the queue, communication with the apps checking for authentication and all other stuffs will be done by mighty GCM )

In order to have an bird-eye overview you can take a look on this image collected form [android hive](http://www.androidhive.info)

[image]

Server side coding is doesn't need you to be expert in php. So you can go through to [this article](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/). It helped me a lot to learn.